# Open Graph has og:type of 'website'

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I constantly keep getting the following error, I'm very confused to where it's getting type website from cause I'm already doing what it's asking...
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3502) Object at URL http://www.prowebdev.org/WooF/API/OpenGraph.php has og:type of 'website'. The property 'picture' requires an object of og:type 'mydogwoofs:picture'. ", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3502
  }
}

<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# mydogwoofs: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/mydogwoofs#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="270765153057909" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="mydogwoofs:picture" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://www.woof.co" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="" /> 
  <meta property="og:description"  content="hola" />  
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: According to FB’s debug tool the meta information you have shown is not contained in the HTML code the URL delivers: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.prowebdev.org%2FWooF%2FAPI%2FOpenGraph.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have any idea why that is? I'm using picture:http://www.prowebdev.org/WooF/API/OpenGraph.php

Comment: I've figured it out! Thanks for leading me in the right direction! The og:url was redirecting to a different page...